# How to convert blob to MP3 in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am recording audio from microphone of the user with MediaRecorder and using Navigator.getUserMedia.

```
getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    this.stream = stream;
    const mimeType = 'audio/mp3';
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    this.mediaRecorder.start();
    const audioChunks = [];
    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });

    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
        type: mimeType});
    });
  }).catch(error => { });
```

I have converted this blob to WAV file in ReactJS with the help of decodeAudioData method of AudioContext. I also used File Reader in this process. But the size of WAV file is too much. Since my usecase is to record the meeting which can go for like 1-2 hours. And for one hour the size is around 350MB.
So I rather need to convert the blob to MP3 has it has relatively less size than WAV.
Please does anyone knows any library to convert blob to MP3 in ReactJS?

Comment: Can't you keep the original opus or vorbis format? Their compression should be good enough. Otherwise, there is no built-in way to do this, you'd have to rely on a library or server-side application to do that, and we don't do software recommendations in here.

Comment: Any recommendations for library. Since I am uploading that audio file to IBM cloud storage from client side so I need to convert to MP3 on the client side only. Any help?

Comment: We don't do library recommendations. But there are many out there able to record your MediaStream to mp3 directly, just search "record audio to mp3 javascript" in your favorite search engine

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert to mp3 the type should be mpeg

```
const mimeType = 'audio/mpeg';
```

I hope I helped you.